# Get email for business inquiries using Youtube API

Tags: email, parsing, web-scraping, youtube

Is there any way to get channel's email for business inquires via Youtube API or are there any other possible methods to do it? I know that email can be received only throughout API by requesting users.info and OAuth2.0, which is not what I really want.

The problem is that I have a list of channels' ids and want to parse emails using them. The only thing I did is parsing emails using regular expressions from channel's description. Also, I struggled with webdriver to emulate person's workflow in browser to catch email from /about page, but there was a captcha, so I gave up.

Comment: I have been wondering of the same thing today. Have you solved it? The captcha seems that YouTube doesn't want people to parse/get emails programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to do it with selenium.

Steps:

1. Get 2 captcha API, for solving those captchas, it very cheap.
2. After that you can initiate everything normally, like logging in to the Gmail account and fetching the emails.

Note: there is a limit restriction of ~15 emails at once, you need to have multiple Gmail accounts and some good geo residential proxies.

If your proxies are authenticated use selenium wire with undetected-chrome-driver